# Cost of storing and retrieving data

Tags: java, input

I am dealing with the case of pattern recognition and for input, I need to read coordinates of points, up to 10000 points from a text file. I need to perform certain calculations on the points read. So, my question is whether I should always read them from the text file when I need to do some calculation or I should store them in some data structure, eg, a 2D array and hence access the values. What difference would there be in terms of storage and time?

---

Edit:

- The language I am using is Java.
- The data structure is user defined that has

  - a constructor that instantiates the object with x and y coordinates.
  - a method to draw the point on standard output.
  - a method to draw a line between two given points.
  - a method to compare the position of two points based on coordinates.
  - a method to compute the slope between two points.
  - an inner class extending Comparable interface that can be used to compare two points.
            The comparison is based on slope made by each point w.r.t a reference point.

PS - I am sorry if the question is a silly one but just wanted to be clear about things than shying back. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are reading from text file then one disk I/O will occur

Comment: http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2011/02/08/how-much-slower-is-disk-vs-ram-latency : The ratio of Disk speed vs Memory speed is the same as the ratio of the speed of a slug vs. the speed of a F17 Jet.

Comment: @ JB Nizet - I was actually wondering about the variation caused with growth of data size. But sure, the infographic and googling about the right term 'disk I/O' do me a lot of help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well storing them in the memory will be the recommended option here, assuming that its a static text file(meaning that the points don't change when you are running the recognition ) as it will really speed up the whole process and 10000 points is not too large to be cached in memory.

Not to mention this point also depends on the fact which language and data structure you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I would still like to seek for a more detailed answer that what is the difference between direct access of text file and between instantiating it as a point (user defined data structure). Also that you have mentioned that 10000 points is not too large to be cached in memory, then what number would be really large? What difference in terms of space storage and time of access would it make?

Comment: @user3264593: use your basic math skills. A point is two int coordinates. That makes 2 x 4 bytes. Each object has an overhead of 16 bytes. So, for 10,000 points, you need 10,000 x 24 bytes = 240 KB. It's a tiny piece of memory.